# How to verify a payment transaction in made in google pay on a NODEMCU through the Google Pay API?

Tags: java, android, stripe-payments, google-pay

The microcontroller in question is a NodeMCU and the application is to Verify payments for a vending machine. The machine displays a QR code for customers to pay through the Google Pay App.
The requirement is to check the bank account for an increase in balance and verify a payment.
I have no experience with the Google Pay API so please suggest the process.
If there's a better platform for payments and verification please feel free to suggest.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like this [specifically a Google Pay thing](https://support.google.com/pay-offline-merchants/answer/9232302?hl=en) and unfortunately Stripe doesn't support that Google Pay functionality directly.

Since this wouldn't work at all for i.e. iPhones, and since I presume you have some kind of server-side application here anyways, you may just want to instead consider building a web app that the QR code directs to, that allows payment in [more ways than just Google Pay](https://stripe.com/docs/stripe-js/elements/payment-request-button).